# Ubuntu + Python3.6 + Apache2_web access error: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-3.6

Ubuntu16(x64) + Python3.6(installed by anaconda) + Django1.11.3(installed by conda) + Apache2.4.18.

With this configuration__ect/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/mblog

WSGIDaemonProcess mblog python-path=/var/www/mblog
WSGIProcessGroup mblog

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mblog/mblog/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/mblog/mblog>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>            
</VirtualHost>
```

and the apache www directory for python project as below:

```
enter code here/var/www/mblog/(755)
|-- manage.py(755)
|       
|-- mblog(dir 755)
|      `|-- wsgi.py(644)
|       `-- urls.py(644)
|-- templates(dir)
|       `-- *.html(644)
```

The wsgi.py is configured as below (the files is granted):

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/mblog/mblog')

# poiting to the project settings
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mblog.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

After all of these config, the browser display:"500 Internal Server Error"

So I look for the error of /var/log/apache2/error.log as below:

```
File "/var/www/mblog/mblog/wsgi.py", line 31, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

I am confused about all of the explain of website explanation but all of these cannot solve this question.

`https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/`

Could you please give me a hand to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You either haven't told mod_wsgi where the Python virtual environment is that you are using and which Django is installed in, or your mod_wsgi is compiled for a different version of Python than you want to use and which Python is installed in.

Check what mod_wsgi is compiled for by doing what is described in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library

For how to set up a Python virtual environment (which is recommended be used), see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: According to you answer, I created a env with conda:     conda create --name python36 python=3.6 , after I active the virtual environment, and restart the apache, I found the apache cannot start with this error  "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: And what did the error logs for Apache and systemd tell you?